# What do the focusIn and focusOut event types mean?

Tags: python, tkinter, focus, tk-toolkit, focusin

I am reading a book on Tkinter and so far making good progress understanding the concepts for a gui I want to make. One thing unexplained in the book is the concept of focusIn and focusOut. I have looked at the tcl.tk explanation and cannot understand what the events mean from that either.

If this is not the correct place to post such a question I apologise but I don't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `focusIn` event occurs when you select a widget so that your keyboard input goes to that widget. For instance, when you click on an input field so you can type into it.

The `focusOut` event occurs when you leave the widget that previously had focus, by moving keyboard focus to some other widget.